# How to "properly" wire up modules (+dependencies) that are shared between apps in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, dependency-management

There are two apps that have a few modules in common, like this:

```
/apps
    /app1
        /.ve
        /requirements.txt
    /app2
        /.ve
        /requirements.txt
/modules
    /module1
        /requirements.txt
    /module2
        /requirements.txt
    /module3
        /requirements.txt
    /module4
        /requirements.txt
```

- app1 depends on `module1` and `module3` and uses virtualenv
- app2 depends on `module2` and `module3` and uses virtualenv
- module3 depends on `module4`
- modules are like 3rd party packages, but are under an active local development. They will only ever be executed by an `application`, so they do not have their own virtualenv
- each app and each module has it's own requirements.txt

**How do I "correctly" wire this thing up?** The goal is to be able to install whole dependency graph for each application in `/apps` using a single command (like `pip install -r requirements.txt`, no custom scripts prefferably)

**Idea #1**:

- add `/modules` to PYTHONPATH
- use `-r ../modules/module1/requirements.txt` syntax in requirements.txt for each app

**The problem**: PIP will not work if any requirement is sepcified in both requirements.txt files (https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2367). If both app1 and module1 depends on django, I need to be able to make this explicit in their corresponding requirements.

**Idea #2**:

- Create an egg/wheel/package/whatever for each module under `/modules`, and reference them in each app's requirements.txt

**The problem**: Creating eggs just for the sake of making `pip` behave properly is a lot of work. Plus development would be harder - I would have to reinstall each egg every time something changes.

Comment: Why do you need to do it with a single `pip install`?  If you call `pip install` separately for each app it should just install what it needs, leaving any already-installed dependencies in place.

Comment: I mean I want to use a single `pip install` *per application* - one for app1 and one for app2. I updated my question to indicate that I want to put each app in a separate virtualenv

Comment: I guess I don't know enough about pip internals on this matter.  Are you saying the `requirement.txt` in the apps directly reference the `requirements.txt` of the modules?  If so, can you just instead specify the modules as normal dependencies and let pip install them normally?

Comment: I notice that the pip [documentation](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html) says: "Requirement files are mostly flat. Maybe MyApp requires Framework, and Framework requires Library. I encourage you to still list all these in a single requirement file; it is the nature of Python programs that there are implicit bindings directly between MyApp and Library."  This suggests that the "supported" way is to have the apps' `requirements.txt` directly reference any dependencies of the modules.

Comment: I can reference a module directly in `requirements.txt` but `pip install` will just copy the files - it makes the module development harder.

Comment: regarding the pip documentation - exactly, that's what `pip freeze` is for;  the problem is that I need pip to know about any changes in `module2` requirements.txt in case I add a new dependency

Comment: Yeah, but what I mean is that the documentation seems to be saying you shouldn't do that.  See the example it gives right after the part I quoted.  It seems to be saying that if you use a `requirements.txt` for `app`, that file should explicitly list all the dependencies, including recursive dependencies.  If you add a dependency to `module2` you are also effectively adding it to `app`, so you need to update the `requirements.txt` in `app`.

Comment: That's correct. I just want to update it using `pip freeze` after pip detects and installs those new recursive dependencies for me (just like with 3rd party packages)

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing these modules, give them a proper `setup.py` and install them in *development mode* to both virtual envs, i.e. with the module activated, `python setup.py develop` the required modules the application virtualenvs.

You could also install both applications in the same virtualenv, if they do not clash.

Comment: Thanks! This is already something! Now, let's assume I add a new dependency to `module3/requirements.txt` - how do I install them? `pip install --upgrade` will remove `.egg-link` created by setuptools and just copy the module files; Of course I can just manually perform `pip install dependency` every time but I hope there is some automated way to do this

Comment: No, you should add them in the `setup.py` requirements and upgrade dependencies with `setup.py develop`.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files - I consider the requirements.txt a secondary feature over the `setup.py` `install_requires`, used to freeze the whole virtual env contents and package conflicts.

Comment: Okay one last issue with that - how do I explicitly specify `module4` as a dependency of `module3`? `install_requires` + `dependency_links` doesn't exactly work even with `--process-dependency-links`

Comment: I guess I can do `setup.py develop` on each dependency for each virtualenv, but this way I become a dependency solver. There must be a better way